# View 3D PDF on iOS using objective-c

Tags: ios, pdf, 3d, autocad

I have at hand a 3D PDF export using AUTOCAD, has some way to view this file in iOS?

Note that do not want to simply display a common PDF, I want to display a 3D object that is in it.

Any solution with other file formats like 3drw is already of great help.

**Edit:**

> Note: I do not mean the applications that are in the apple store, what
>   I need is a way to implement the code as necessary to integrate it
>   into the app I'm working on.

Comment: Can you export to COLLADA? SceneKit supports that. This is almost the limit of my insight into that.

Answer (score -1):

3D PDF viewing on iOS is definitely possible. But it works a bit differently than it does on a PC. When you view a 3D PDF on a PC, Adobe Reader displays both the 2D and 3D portions of the PDF file. On iOS, the 3D portion is viewed using a separate app. CHeck out the free 3D PDF Reader from Tech Soft 3D for this:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/3d-pdf-reader

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think you did not understand my question, I just edit it to make it more clear ... I need a way for the implementation and not any application that already exists.